# Cpalead subid postback variable

Tags: codeigniter

I am implementing a cpalead widget in codeigniter. I need track the user that complete a survey and redirect him to distinct pages. I know about postback subid feature, my question is: Can i pass various data chunks across this variable? ie: &subid=page_userid_ip_etc
Thanks.-

Comment: Surely you can find better tags for this question than [tag:marketing].

Comment: @matt_ball marketing is a accepted tag, and cpalead is a marketing service. please put it back.

Comment: I added the tag back in, but just FYI you could have just as easily done that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass basically whatever you want back in the subid.  Encoded data, and ID int which ties to a record in a DB, whatever you want.  There may be size limits, so an int that ties to a db record is not a bad idea.